# How to add, subtract memory addresses in C?

Tags: c

I have a normal code that requires subtracting two memory addresses of variables inside the code. I can not take any new variable to store the addresses. The end result is calculating the difference between two addresses. I feel that I've no use of pointers since I need the value of the address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int p=50, q=100;

    printf("Address is : %d\n\n", &p);
    printf("Address is : %d\n\n", &q);
    printf("Difference is %d bytes\n", &q - &p);

    return 0;
}
```

> Address is : 60566160
>
> Address is : 60566164
>
> Difference is 1 bytes

Comment: Please don’t post code as an image. You didn’t draw it, you wrote it, so include it as text and format it properly with the code button on the toolbar.

Comment: What's your question? In your code sample you show an explicit example of how to subtract memory addresses.

Comment: "uintptr_t"----- Is it any standard function? I need to use standard things, as I'm a new student of CSE

Comment: I know C pretty well and I really don't understand what you're asking for or what you're trying to do. It's confusing the way you've asked it.  Why do you need address arithmetic? You're using pointers because you say you need the difference between addresses and then say you have no use of pointers. What does that mean? Seems ambiguous.

Comment: Maybe if you described more about what you're trying to accomplish with the address arithmetic we could figure out what you're really trying to ask?

Comment: @BillLynch My question is how I can get two memory address and subtract them "inside the code"  as this would be the distance between two variables in computer's memory. I can not take any new variable to hold those memory addresses.

Comment: @SevenSea -- subtraction for pointers is only defined for pointers to the same array object or to one past the last element of that object. A single integer counts for this purpose as an array of one element, so pointer subtraction will be defined for two integers `p` and `q` if they happen to be next to each other in memory. The result of a pointer subtraction is _not_ the number of bytes between addresses, but the difference in array subscripts (i.e., 1 for pointers to adjacent elements, as here).

Comment: Note that you need to cast addresses to `void *` before printing with `%p`: `printf("address of p: %p\n", (void *) &p);`. Also note that the result of a pointer subtraction has type `ptrdiff_t`, which should be printed with `%td`: `printf("difference (&q - &p): %td\n", &q - &p);`.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard defines subtraction of pointers only for two pointers that point into the same array, treating “one past the end of the array” as part of that and treating a single object as if it were an array of one element. The result is the number of array elements between the two locations the pointers point to.

There are times when we must write code that subtracts addresses that do not conform to those conditions. For example, when writing various parts of operating systems, we may need to use raw addresses and perform calculations involving them. In such cases, we need to rely on specifications from the compiler we use, since the C standard does not provide enough support.

Primarily, there are two techniques: Converting to a `char *` or convert to an integer.

In C, a `char` is the fundamental unit of memory; it is one byte by definition. Given pointers `&p` and `&q`, we can convert them to `char *`, consider all of the memory address space to be one large array of bytes, and subtract them to get the number of bytes between them:

```
(char *) &p - (char *) &q
```

Again, the behavior here is not defined by the C standard. You must use a compiler that treats pointers as “flat” addresses and supports this operation.

The second method is to convert to an integer. The C standard provides a little support in this; it defines `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` to be integer types that are sufficient to contain all the information of addresses. They are declared by including the header `<stdint.h>`, but it is optional for a C implementation to define them. We can convert pointers to these types, but the result is not fully defined by the C standard. C implementations are required to define the result. GCC’s [documentation for this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation) is very spare, not what I would consider good complete documentation, but it suggests the results of the conversion are the same bits used by the underlying machine for addresses. So, in machines with “flat” address spaces, the results of converting pointers to `uintptr_t` with GCC are essentially indices within an array of bytes filling memory. In that case, we can convert the pointers and subtract:

```
(uintptr_t) &p - (uintptr_t) &q
```

To get a signed difference instead of unsigned, we use `intptr_t`:

```
(intptr_t) &p - (intptr_t) &q
```

Note there are some inherent problems in attempting to describe the relative positions of pointers using signed integers. If we have a 16-bit address space, we can have addresses from 0 to 65535. Then the difference between two addresses can range from −65535 (subtracting address 65535 from address 0) to +65535 (subtracting address 0 from address 65535). A 16-bit signed integer can only represent values from −32768 to +32767. So a signed integer of the same width as the addresses cannot represent every possible value. If you need to work with the differences of addresses that might be extremely far apart, then you need an even wider integer.

To print the address, conversion specifiers for the types declared in `<stdint.h>` are defined in `<inttypes.h>`. We can print an `intptr_t` value using `"%" PRIdPTR`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int p, q;
    printf("&p = %p.\n", (void *) &p);
    printf("&q = %p.\n", (void *) &q);
    printf("&p - &q = %" PRIdPTR ".\n", (intptr_t) &p - (intptr_t) &q);
}
```

### Notes

To print a pointer, use the `printf` conversion specification `%p` and convert the pointer to `void *`, as shown above.

When two pointers are subtracted, the type of the result is `ptrdiff_t`, defined in `<stddef.h>`. To print a `ptrdiff_t`, use `%td`:

```
printf("Difference = %td.\n", (char *) &p - (char *) &q);
```

If `intptr_t` is insufficient, you can try using the widest signed type in your C implementation, `intmax_t`:

```
printf("&p - &q = %" PRIdMAX ".\n", (intmax_t) &p - (intmax_t) &q);
```

This is not guaranteed to be sufficient; `intmax_t` may be the same width as `intptr_t` and may fail to represent the distances between widely separated addresses.